# Electron Window Handler to ffi c Library

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, node-ffi

I have a native library loaded which expect a Window Handler like in this C example:
[image]

(Translated in english: Callingexample in C)
But how can i pass with node ffi the electron NativeWindowHandle to work with my dll. I have not the source code of the dll, only a description pdf in german. So how can i pass the handler ? And which type i need to set in ffi as parameter ?
The only other information i have, in c#, if you import the dll, you can pass it like this:

```
[DllImport("homeputer.dll")]
private static extern int homeputer_SetWindowHandle(int handl);
```

But how can i get this to work in electron/node-ffi.

Nils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know now how it works:

```
ref.get(handler, 0, 'int')
```

This will return the correct int.